# Optical Properties of Heavily Doped Silicon in the Visible and Near Infrared

Tags: resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, models, photonics, data

I am looking for a model of the changes in the complex refractive index of doped Silicon based on the doping level and type in the visible and near-infrared wavelengths (400-1000 nm). I have seen people refer to the Drude-Plasma model, but I could not find any reported and verified data for the coefficients in the model (effective mass and mobility of electron/hole ) at these wavelengths.

Please let me know how I can find this data or any other verified model.

Comment: How heavy is ‘heavy’? Are you talking degeneratively doped?

Comment: Googling "optical properties of doped silicon" sure pulls up a bunch of papers.

Comment: @JonCuster A doping of around 1e20 cm^-3 and above is considered heavy, as far as I am concerned. And, about the googling, I have googled and I didn't find anything in the wavelength range 700-1000 nm. I want to know if there are any well-known papers that everyone uses.

Comment: I think I'd start with Jellison (https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.46.1414) and its references, and then move on to https://opg.optica.org/josa/fulltext.cfm?uri=josa-50-7-717&id=52091 and https://pubs.aip.org/aip/apl/article/56/17/1694/56898/Optical-and-electronic-properties-of-doped-silicon to ssee how they address things (and their references). 1E20 is quite highly doped silicon.